# How to retrieve the parts of the same long SMS received from the AT+CMGL command

Tags: sms, gsm, at-command

I have an application interfaced with a GSM Modem where I receive many SMS and display them in a user interface using AT+CMGL command in text mode.
When I have short messages, everything is fine. I can retrieve all messages.

```
AT+CMGL="ALL"

+CMGL: 0,"REC UNREAD","+111111","","23/01/03,16:57:38+04"
This is message 1
+CMGL: 2,"REC UNREAD","+111111","","23/01/03,16:58:03+04"
This is message 2
+CMGL: 1,"REC UNREAD","+111111","","23/01/03,16:58:04+04"
This is message 3

OK
```

When I have long messages divided in many parts, because an SMS has a limited number of characters, I see them like many short messages.

```
AT+CMGL="ALL"

+CMGL: 0,"REC UNREAD","+111111","","23/01/03,18:16:20+04"
This is message 1 : message 1 message 1 message 1 message 1 message 1 message 1 message 1 message 1
+CMGL: 1,"REC UNREAD","+111111","","23/01/03,18:16:21+04"
This is second part of message 1
+CMGL: 2,"REC UNREAD","+111111","","23/01/03,18:19:04+04"
This is message 2

OK
```

Is there an indication (a parameter in AT+CMGL command) that show me all parts of the same message.
How can I retrieve all parts of the same Message so I can regroup them and display it in my user interface.

Thank You in advance for your time and your help :)

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AT+CMGL` command has two modes, *text mode* and *PDU mode*. The technical name for splitting up long messages into several "normal" length sms messages is *multi-part*. `AT+CMGL` only supports multi-part in PDU mode.

For more details see the [3GPP 27.005 specification](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27005.htm).

Comment: Hi @hlovdal, Thank you for your useful answer. I will launch the development of a branch based on the PDU Mode in order to better understand it.

Comment: Please note how modules vendors, for example Telit, can support custom commands providing support for multipart messages in text mode (in case of Telit, commands like `#CMGL` are supported)